# How to remove the first zero in a form textbox after first 2 characters in a javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make sure that the Form Textbox with ID input_1_4 has the right telephone format.  To achieve this, every time a user enters a number on the textbox field, the script needs to eliminate the first zero that comes within the first 4 characters.

THIS IS MY JQUERY  FUNCTION. What should I put to achieve my goal?

```
jQuery('#input_1_4').change(function() {


        }
    });
});
```

If the user enters +408765432, the script will remove zero because of it within the first 4 characters.  The expected result must be +48765432.

If the user enters +4508765432, the result must be +458765432 because it is also within the first 4 characters.

However, if the user enters +4560876543 - The zero will not be removed because it is already the 5th character.  The expected result is the same: +4560876543

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest thing would be to take a slice of the first four characters and replace the zero, then concat the rest of the string back together:

```js
function removeZero(s) {
    return s.slice(0,4).replace('0', '') + s.slice(4,)
}

let s1 = "+4560876543"
let s2 = "+408765432"
let s3 = "4508765432"
 
console.log(removeZero(s1))
console.log(removeZero(s2))
console.log(removeZero(s3))

// only removes the first zero
console.log(removeZero("4008765432"))
```

An alternative is to use a pure regex, thought this is a little harder to debug and read:

```js
function removeZero(s) {
    return s.replace(/(^[^0]{0,3})0/, '$1') 
}
console.log("+4560876543 => ", removeZero('+4560876543'))
console.log("460876543 => ", removeZero('460876543'))
console.log("0460876543 => ", removeZero('0460876543'))
console.log("+40560876543 => ", removeZero('40560876543'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#input_1_4').change(function() {
        jQuery('#input_1_4').val(jQuery('#input_1_4').val().substring(0,4).replace("0", "")+jQuery('#input_1_4').val().substring(4))

        }
    });
});
```

Note: I do not use jQuery that much, nor do I know that this will even run without errors, but hopefully this can give you an idea of what to do:
1. Get the value of the form 2. Get the first four digits of the form (substring) 3. Replace all 0's with empty characters (use regex and replace) 4. Add the remaining digits back in and set the value of the text field.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
     var myinput = "+40150544";
     function removeit (input) {
            var arr =  input.split('');
                 arr.map((x,i)=> { i<4 && x==0 ? arr.splice(i,1)  : x})
                      return arr.join('');
            };
            removeitit(myinput)
```